# How to popup a Menu automatically without any action in SWT?

Tags: java, events, menu, swt, popupmenu

How to popup a Menu automatically without any action/event in SWT? I can popup/display a popup menu by mouse right click on the button. But I want is to popup the menu without any button action.

```
    final Button btnNewgroup = new Button(compositeTextClient, SWT.NONE);
    Menu menu = new Menu(btnNewgroup);
    btnNewgroup.setMenu(menu);
    MenuItem mntmNewItem1 = new MenuItem(menu, SWT.NONE);
    mntmNewItem1.setText("New Item");
    MenuItem mntmNewItem2 = new MenuItem(menu, SWT.NONE);
    mntmNewItem2.setText("New Item2");
```

Comment: The answer is essentially the same as the left click except the code is not in a selection listener.

Comment: So answer is setting menu.setVisible(true). Thanks a lot.